# Angular/RxJS - Delay stream until previous stream finished

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm building a notifications component which should show notifications to the user. When multiple notifications gets created at once it should queue them.

Right now it shows the first notification just fine, but after that it triggers 2 notifications at the same time (see current output below). It doesn't wait for the previous notification to show and then hide again before showing the next one.

**notifications.api.ts**:

```
public notifications = new Subject<INotificationEvent>();
public notifications$ = this.notifications.asObservable();
```

**notifications.component.ts**:

```
private finished = new Subject();

constructor(private notifications: NotificationsApi) {}

zip(this.notificationsApi.notifications$, this.notificationsApi.notifications, (i, s) => s).pipe(
  tap(() => {

    if (!this.isActive) {
      this.finished.next();
    }
  }),
  delayWhen(() => this.finished),
  delay(450),
  tap((event: INotificationEvent) => {
    this.notification = event;
    this.isActive = true;
    this.cd.markForCheck();
    console.log(this.notification);
    console.log('showing');
  }),
  delay(this.hideAfter),
  tap(() => {
    this.isActive = false;
    this.cd.markForCheck();
    console.log('closing');
  }),
  delay(450)
).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('finishing');
  this.finished.next();
});
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  this.notifications.newNotification({message: `${i}`, theme: 'primary'});
  i++;
}, 2000);
```

**Current output**:

```
{message: "0", theme: "primary"}
showing
closing
finishing
{message: "1", theme: "primary"}
showing
{message: "2", theme: "primary"}
showing
closing
finishing
{message: "3", theme: "primary"}
showing
{message: "4", theme: "primary"}
showing
closing
closing
finishing
finishing
{message: "5", theme: "primary"}
showing
{message: "6", theme: "primary"}
```

**Desired output**:

```
{message: "0", theme: "primary"}
showing
closing
finishing
{message: "1", theme: "primary"}
showing
closing
finishing
{message: "2", theme: "primary"}
showing
closing
finishing
{message: "3", theme: "primary"}
showing
closing
finishing
{message: "4", theme: "primary"}
showing
closing
finishing
{message: "5", theme: "primary"}
showing
closing
finishing
{message: "6", theme: "primary"}
showing
closing
finishing
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: So you want to show one notification for `450ms` then hide it and show another one if there're any queued?

Comment: @martin Each notification is shown for 3900ms in total, 450ms is the animation for hide/show then it's visible for 3000ms on top of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe it seems to me that you could achieve the same much easily with `concatMap` and `delay`.

In this example every button click represents one notification. Each notification takes 2s. It depends on what you want to do in the observer but if you don't need the notification at all you can leave it empty (otherwise you'll need probably `startWith`). Multiple notifications are queued inside `concatMap` and executed one after another.

```
const notification$ = fromEvent(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0], 'click');

notification$.pipe(
  concatMap(event => of(event).pipe(
    tap(v => console.log('showing', v)),
    delay(2000),
    tap(v => console.log('closing', v)),
  ))
).subscribe();
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nqtfzm?file=index.ts

Comment: Such an elegant solution! Works perfectly :D Also had to change the subject type in the service to a `ReplaySubject` so it would pick up premature calls to the service. Many thanks!